# How to read Python file parameters into Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I am building Docker images in my Azure DevOps pipeline.  I tag the image with the version of the image. The version is stored in `prodInfo.py` and is of the following structure:

```
title = "Product A"
description = "Description"
version = "0.1.0.0"
```

I was wondering how I can load the `version` info into Azure DevOps so I can provide it to the `tag` field within my `.yaml` pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same job, before the Docker build task, you can add a [Bash task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/bash-v3?view=azure-pipelines) to read the **`prodInfo.py`** file and extract the version number from the line. And then use the logging command "[**SetVariable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)" to set the extracted version number as a pipeline variable for use on the Docker build task.

Below is a sample as reference.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Get tag version'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          lineStr=$(sed -n -e '/^version = "/p' relative/path/to/prodInfo.py)
          echo $lineStr
          tagVer=$(echo $lineStr | cut -d'"' -f 2)
          echo $tagVer
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=tagVersion;]$tagVer"
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print tagVersion'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "tagVersion = $(tagVersion)"

# On the subsequent Docker build task, 
# you can pass the pipeline varibale $(tagVersion) to the Tags field.
```

Result:
[image]